# Writing an IRC Bot from scratch

Tags: c#, parsing, regex, reinventing-the-wheel, wpf

I have been learning C# for a couple years now, and using small projects to help myself learn.  My most recent project is a complete rewrite of my first C# project that just got out of hand (the old one).

I would really appreciate it if you could take the time to take a look at it and provide some critiques.

Some notes about the project:

- I wanted to write most everything from scratch instead of using libraries in order to better learn.
- I am thinking of using a different database, possibly one that does not need to be installed that I can distribute with the code.

Here is a link to the source code: [Github](https://github.com/uncled1023/Combot/tree/8ac5907a2cbcd8f01ea7cdd0230e4a8546a86bf4)

Here are some of the more important/ugliest portions of code:

### ParseTCPMessage() in Messages.cs

```
internal async void ParseTCPMessage(string tcpMessage)
{
    DateTime messageTime = DateTime.Now;
    Regex messageRegex = new Regex(@"^:(?<Sender>[^\s]+)\s(?<Type>[^\s]+)\s(?<Recipient>[^\s]+)\s?:?(?<Args>.*)", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex senderRegex = new Regex(@"^(?<Nick>[^\s]+)!(?<Realname>[^\s]+)@(?<Host>[^\s]+)", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex pingRegex = new Regex(@"^PING :(?<Message>.+)", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex pongRegex = new Regex(@"^PONG :(?<Message>.+)", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex errorRegex = new Regex(@"^ERROR :(?<Message>.+)", RegexOptions.None);
    Regex CTCPRegex = new Regex(@"^\u0001(?<Command>[^\s]+)\s?(?<Args>.*)\u0001", RegexOptions.None);

    string[] messages = tcpMessage.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    foreach (string message in messages)
    {
        if (messageRegex.IsMatch(message))
        {
            Match match = messageRegex.Match(message);
            string type = match.Groups["Type"].Value;
            string sender = match.Groups["Sender"].Value;
            string recipient = match.Groups["Recipient"].Value;
            string args = match.Groups["Args"].Value;
            Match senderMatch = senderRegex.Match(sender);
            string senderNick = sender;
            string senderRealname = sender;
            string senderHost = sender;
            if (senderMatch.Success)
            {
                senderNick = senderMatch.Groups["Nick"].Value;
                senderRealname = senderMatch.Groups["Realname"].Value;
                senderHost = senderMatch.Groups["Host"].Value;
            }

            int replyCode;
            if (int.TryParse(type, out replyCode))
            {
                // The message was a reply to a command sent
                if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IRCReplyCode), replyCode))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        if (ServerReplyEvent != null)
                        {
                            ServerReplyEvent(this,
                                new ServerReplyMessage()
                                {
                                    TimeStamp = messageTime,
                                    ReplyCode = (IRCReplyCode) replyCode,
                                    Message = args
                                });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(IRCErrorCode), replyCode))
                {
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        if (ServerReplyEvent != null)
                        {
                            ServerReplyEvent(this,
                                new ServerErrorMessage()
                                {
                                    TimeStamp = messageTime,
                                    ErrorCode = (IRCErrorCode) replyCode,
                                    Message = args
                                });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    // The message was a private message to a channel or nick
                    case "PRIVMSG":
                        if (CTCPRegex.IsMatch(args))
                        {
                            Match ctcpMatch = CTCPRegex.Match(args);
                            CTCPMessage ctcpMessage = new CTCPMessage();
                            ctcpMessage.Sender = new Nick()
                            {
                                Nickname = senderNick,
                                Realname = senderRealname,
                                Host = senderHost
                            };
                            ctcpMessage.Command = ctcpMatch.Groups["Command"].Value;
                            ctcpMessage.Arguments = ctcpMatch.Groups["Args"].Value;

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (CTCPMessageReceivedEvent != null)
                                {
                                    CTCPMessageReceivedEvent(this, ctcpMessage);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (recipient.StartsWith("&") || recipient.StartsWith("#"))
                            {
                                ChannelMessage msg = new ChannelMessage();
                                msg.Channel = recipient;
                                msg.Sender = new Nick()
                                {
                                    Nickname = senderNick,
                                    Realname = senderRealname,
                                    Host = senderHost
                                };
                                msg.Message = args;

                                await Task.Run(() =>
                                {
                                    if (ChannelMessageReceivedEvent != null)
                                    {
                                        ChannelMessageReceivedEvent(this, msg);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                PrivateMessage msg = new PrivateMessage();
                                msg.Sender = new Nick()
                                {
                                    Nickname = senderNick,
                                    Realname = senderRealname,
                                    Host = senderHost
                                };
                                msg.Message = args;

                                await Task.Run(() =>
                                {
                                    if (PrivateMessageReceivedEvent != null)
                                    {
                                        PrivateMessageReceivedEvent(this, msg);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    // The message was a notice to a channel or nick
                    case "NOTICE":
                        if (CTCPRegex.IsMatch(args))
                        {
                            Match ctcpMatch = CTCPRegex.Match(args);
                            CTCPMessage ctcpMessage = new CTCPMessage();
                            ctcpMessage.Sender = new Nick()
                            {
                                Nickname = senderNick,
                                Realname = senderRealname,
                                Host = senderHost
                            };
                            ctcpMessage.Command = ctcpMatch.Groups["Command"].Value;
                            ctcpMessage.Arguments = ctcpMatch.Groups["Args"].Value;

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (CTCPNoticeReceivedEvent != null)
                                {
                                    CTCPNoticeReceivedEvent(this, ctcpMessage);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (recipient.StartsWith("&") || recipient.StartsWith("#"))
                        {
                            ChannelNotice msg = new ChannelNotice();
                            msg.Channel = recipient;
                            msg.Sender = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                            msg.Message = args;

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (ChannelNoticeReceivedEvent != null)
                                {
                                    ChannelNoticeReceivedEvent(this, msg);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            PrivateNotice msg = new PrivateNotice();
                            msg.Sender = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                            msg.Message = args;

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (PrivateNoticeReceivedEvent != null)
                                {
                                    PrivateNoticeReceivedEvent(this, msg);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    // The message was a mode change message for a channel or nick
                    case "MODE":
                        if (recipient.StartsWith("&") || recipient.StartsWith("#"))
                        {
                            ChannelModeChangeInfo modeMsg = new ChannelModeChangeInfo();
                            modeMsg.Modes = new List<ChannelModeInfo>();
                            modeMsg.Channel = recipient;
                            modeMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };

                            string[] modeArgs = args.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            List<string> argList = modeArgs.ToList();
                            argList.RemoveAt(0);
                            modeMsg.Modes.AddRange(_IRC.ParseChannelModeString(modeArgs[0].TrimStart(':'), string.Join(" ", argList)));

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (ChannelModeChangeEvent != null)
                                {
                                    ChannelModeChangeEvent(this, modeMsg);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            UserModeChangeInfo modeMsg = new UserModeChangeInfo();
                            modeMsg.Modes = new List<UserModeInfo>();
                            modeMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };

                            string[] modeArgs = args.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            char[] modeInfo = modeArgs[0].TrimStart(':').ToCharArray();
                            bool set = true;
                            foreach (char mode in modeInfo)
                            {
                                if (mode.Equals('-'))
                                {
                                    set = false;
                                }
                                else if (mode.Equals('+'))
                                {
                                    set = true;
                                }
                                else if (mode.ToString() != string.Empty)
                                {
                                    UserModeInfo newMode = new UserModeInfo();
                                    newMode.Set = set;
                                    newMode.Mode = (UserMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserMode), mode.ToString());
                                    modeMsg.Modes.Add(newMode);
                                }
                            }

                            await Task.Run(() =>
                            {
                                if (UserModeChangeEvent != null)
                                {
                                    UserModeChangeEvent(this, modeMsg);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                    // The message was a topic change for a channel
                    case "TOPIC":
                        TopicChangeInfo topicMsg = new TopicChangeInfo();
                        topicMsg.Channel = recipient;
                        topicMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                        topicMsg.Topic = args;

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (TopicChangeEvent != null)
                            {
                                TopicChangeEvent(this, topicMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was a nick change
                    case "NICK":
                        NickChangeInfo nickMsg = new NickChangeInfo();
                        nickMsg.OldNick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                        nickMsg.NewNick = new Nick() { Nickname = recipient.TrimStart(':') };

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (NickChangeEvent != null)
                            {
                                NickChangeEvent(this, nickMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was an invite to a channel
                    case "INVITE":
                        InviteChannelInfo inviteMsg = new InviteChannelInfo();
                        inviteMsg.Requester = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                        inviteMsg.Recipient = new Nick() { Nickname = recipient };
                        inviteMsg.Channel = args;

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (InviteChannelEvent != null)
                            {
                                InviteChannelEvent(this, inviteMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was a nick joining a channel
                    case "JOIN":
                        JoinChannelInfo joinMsg = new JoinChannelInfo();
                        joinMsg.Channel = recipient.TrimStart(':');
                        joinMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (JoinChannelEvent != null)
                            {
                                JoinChannelEvent(this, joinMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was a nick parting a channel
                    case "PART":
                        PartChannelInfo partMsg = new PartChannelInfo();
                        partMsg.Channel = recipient;
                        partMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (PartChannelEvent != null)
                            {
                                PartChannelEvent(this, partMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was a nick being kicked from a channel
                    case "KICK":
                        KickInfo kickMsg = new KickInfo();
                        kickMsg.Channel = recipient;
                        kickMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                        string[] argSplit = args.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                        kickMsg.KickedNick = new Nick() { Nickname = argSplit[0], Realname = argSplit[0], Host = argSplit[0] };

                        List<string> reasonArgs = argSplit.ToList<string>();
                        reasonArgs.RemoveAt(0);
                        kickMsg.Reason = string.Join(" ", reasonArgs.ToArray()).Remove(0, 1);

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (KickEvent != null)
                            {
                                KickEvent(this, kickMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    // The message was a nick quiting the irc network
                    case "QUIT":
                        QuitInfo quitMsg = new QuitInfo();
                        quitMsg.Nick = new Nick() { Nickname = senderNick, Realname = senderRealname, Host = senderHost };
                        quitMsg.Message = string.Join(" ", recipient.Remove(0, 1), args);

                        await Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            if (QuitEvent != null)
                            {
                                QuitEvent(this, quitMsg);
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (pingRegex.IsMatch(message)) // The message was a PING
        {
            Match match = pingRegex.Match(message);
            PingInfo ping = new PingInfo();
            ping.Message = match.Groups["Message"].Value;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (PingEvent != null)
                {
                    PingEvent(this, ping);
                }
            });
        }
        else if (pongRegex.IsMatch(message)) // The message was a PONG
        {
            Match match = pongRegex.Match(message);
            PongInfo pong = new PongInfo();
            pong.Message = match.Groups["Message"].Value;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (PongEvent != null)
                {
                    PongEvent(this, pong);
                }
            });
        }
        else if (errorRegex.IsMatch(message)) // The message was a server error
        {
            Match match = errorRegex.Match(message);
            ErrorMessage error = new ErrorMessage();
            error.Message = match.Groups["Message"].Value;

            if (ErrorMessageEvent != null)
            {
                ErrorMessageEvent(this, error);
            }
        }

        string rawMessage = message;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (RawMessageEvent != null)
            {
                RawMessageEvent(this, rawMessage);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For performance's sake, and for declaring intent, I'd move those `Regex`es out of the method and as `static readonly` class-level member variables. And in place of  `RegexOptions.None` I'd use `RegexOptions.Compiled`.

Comment: Also, your event raising pattern could run afoul of race conditions in which the event handler is disconnected between checking if it is null and raising it. The pattern *should* be: `var rawMessageEvent = RawMessageEvent; if (rawMessageEvent != null) { rawMessageEvent(this, rawMessage); }`. Assigning to a local variable keeps the view of its value consistent.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious improvement would be to first extract methods out of each `case` in that disastrous `switch(type)` block... and then to break each `if...else` block into its own methods too - the idea being to reduce nesting, and come up with *small* methods that *do little*.

Actually the first thing to extract is near the beginning of the loop: each match possibility belongs in its own method.

And then once you've extracted them into their own method, you can extract each one into a *strategy pattern*, because what you're doing can be stated as follows:

- Find a regex pattern that matches the input
- Use the matching regex to parse the input
- Fire up an event that's specific to the type of pattern we matched

Your code is very *procedural*, which is rather unusual in the *object-oriented* paradigm C# is offering.

I would think more in terms of *objects* here: there's a *strategy* to adopt depending on the type of message you're receiving - each *strategy* belongs in its own class. And since all these *strategies* are really doing the same thing, they should *share an interface*, so that your main loop can call any of them, without *actually caring which one it's calling*.

Comment: Thanks, yea, there are some duplicate actions within the nesting I can pull out to a function.  Then I could keep the case statement for only determining what kind of message it is, and call the respective function.

Answer (score 4):

The very length of your code, and the complexity of the routines, makes it hard to read. After you refactor it into shorter routines as @Mat'sMug suggested, post it again and you'll get more reviews.

As it stands, I can only make a few observations:

- Did you check to see if it might be worthwhile to create long-lived `Regex` objects with `RegexOptions.Compiled`? `Regex` does do automatic caching, but that only works inside `static` methods.
- To save on memory usage, you could write a string splitter that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` using `yield return`, since you're only iterating over it using `foreach`.
- in the `Regex`es where you're only matching one thing, you don't need to name the capturing group.
- does the check for `if (ServerReplyEvent != null)` need to be inside the `await`? (and similarly for others)